# Thermal and RGB multi view image registration

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, image-registration

I have an IR and RGB camera set up such that they are 2cm apart from each other (horizontally).
My goal is to fuse both the images (RGB and IR) to obtain a more informative image. Because of the offset between the RGB and the IR data, both the images do not match. Is there a way to align the images so that they are on the same coordinate system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How about sharing your images to allow folk to help you better? Have a read here... https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/31/image-alignment-and-registration-with-opencv/

Comment: Does _"register"_ mean record? Does _"fuse"_ mean blend (overlay)? Are you a programmer looking to write such software? If not a coder then maybe try **FFmpeg**. It might allow inputs from two camera and then you can add some layer blending command...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to perform an edge detection (or something similar to reduce the amount of information in both images), and then to make a wrap of one image onto the other.

If you are using OpenCV, I suggest using findTransformECC() method ([doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga1aa357007eaec11e9ed03500ecbcbe47)) to find the transformation matrix needed to get the best overlay between your images.

Than you can warp the second image using this transformation matrix with warpAffine() method ([doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983)).